# React native windows - app certification kit failed

Tags: windows, react-native, uwp, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I'm making simple react-native app. Android version works fine (already on Google Play). 
Windows version is also working but It cannot pass through certification kit app.
I've made release-bundle build according documentation:

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/docs/RunningOnDeviceWindows.md

App certification kit return errors:

> Type ReactNativeWebViewBridge.MessagePostedEventArgs in file ReactNativeWebViewBridge.winmd is not sealed and does not have the ComposableAttribute. Unsealed types must have ComposableAttribute.

and

> API getenv in api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. ImagePipelineNative.dll calls this API.

Built with Visual Studio 2017.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type ReactNativeWebViewBridge.MessagePostedEventArgs in file ReactNativeWebViewBridge.winmd is not sealed and does not have the ComposableAttribute. Unsealed types must have ComposableAttribute.

The error message has explained clearly. You need to use `sealed` modifier to the `MessagePostedEventArgs` class in ReactNativeWebViewBridge. If you didn't use `sealed`, you need to use `ComposableAttribute`. More information about `ComposableAttribute`, you could refer to James McNellis's answer in this thread:[What is the ComposableAttribute in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735517/what-is-the-composableattribute-in-winrt)

> API getenv in api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. ImagePipelineNative.dll calls this API.

This error meant that ImagePipelineNative.dll calls some unsupported APIs in UWP. You need to create an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues) in react-native's repository.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I posted this issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1401

Comment: It's a bug in react-native-windows. Issue is solving. Thank you.